# Cross-Browser Colour Management for PNGs

Tags: cross-browser, png, gimp, color-management

I apologise in advance if SO is not the place for this. This seemed the most appropriate Stack Exchange, but still not ideal...

Anyway, I have a number of PNG images on a website I'm developing. They look great in Firefox and IE, but when I check on my iPhone, the colours are all wrong (sometimes dramatically). After a bit of Googling, I found that the problem is due to colour management in Safari and my PNGs using some other profile.

I'm using the GIMP to make my images and I found [this](http://www.firewing1.com/node/14) blog post about how to fix it. However, I tried this and it had no effect. The thing is, I don't seem to have any ICC profiles installed on my machine, so I downloaded the ones I found [here](http://www.adobe.com/support/downloads/product.jsp?product=62&platform=windows); but still no luck... I also found [this](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/GammaCorrectionAndColorCorrectionPNGIsStillTooHard.aspx) link in SO's search side panel as I've been writing; but removing the gamma correction when I save the PNG doesn't do the job, either.

Can anyone point me in the right direction, to get my images to look right everywhere?

Comment: I followed "Method 1", as described on [this page](http://morris-photographics.com/photoshop/articles/png-gamma.html), whereby all the colourspace data is stripped out. It had no effect, so I'm giving up for now :P Quite annoying as most of my users will probably be Mac/Safari users...

Answer (score 1):

So likely your browser treats CSS colors as described in http://hsivonen.iki.fi/png-gamma/ which, of course, does not match up. Instead of inserting sRGB you can also remove the whole gAMA chuck or embedded profile, which may increase your odds by a tiny bit.

Comment: Tried that; see comment on OP... Thanks, all the same :)

Comment: A bit late now but you might want to try gamma-adjusting the picture to 1.8 (i.e. by 1.8/2.2 ~ 0.9 or vice versa), and give it a gAMA chunk of 1.8. Then, 1.8-clients will look fine anyway and spec-conforming sRGB-clients will, too.

Comment: I'll try this next time and report back! Thanks :)